# Show files in tkinter Scrollbar

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I tried to modify the Scrollbar from Tkdoc (http://www.tkdocs.com/tutorial/morewidgets.html#scrollbar) in order to show the filelist of a folder but it does not work. Can someone explain me why? and how to fix it.

Thanks a lot.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import os

def fileName():
    path="C:\\temp"
    dir=os.listdir(path)
    for fn in dir:
        print(fn)


root = Tk()
l = Listbox(root, height=5)
l.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(N,W,E,S))
s = ttk.Scrollbar(root, orient=VERTICAL, command=l.yview)
s.grid(column=1, row=0, sticky=(N,S))
l['yscrollcommand'] = s.set
ttk.Sizegrip().grid(column=1, row=1, sticky=(S,E))
root.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
l.insert(fileName)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should specify where to insert

`l.insert(END, filename)`

In your code, you insert function filename. Insert return value of filename function.

I renamed `fileName` to `get_filename`, and modified it to return filename list.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import os

def get_filenames():
    path = r"C:\temp"
    return os.listdir(path)


root = Tk()
l = Listbox(root, height=5)
l.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(N,W,E,S))
s = ttk.Scrollbar(root, orient=VERTICAL, command=l.yview)
s.grid(column=1, row=0, sticky=(N,S))
l['yscrollcommand'] = s.set
ttk.Sizegrip().grid(column=1, row=1, sticky=(S,E))
root.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
for filename in get_filenames():
    l.insert(END, filename)
root.mainloop()
```